# Spring boot kafka listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a call back for Kafka events with Springboot:

```
@KafkaHandler
fun consume(@Payload response: CustomObject) {
    ...
}
```

When I run the unit tests all is good, they all pass.

As soon as I add another endpoint:

```
@KafkaHandler
fun debug0Consume(@Payload handle: String, @Payload response: CustomObject) {
    ...
}
```

I expect the original callback `consume(@Payload response: CustomObject)` to continue to be executed. Instead none of the two callbacks are executed.

I put debug lines in both of them, and they are not called (besides the fact that all tests fail ofcourse).

What is happening here? Why adding a new Kafka event listener causes the Springboot framework not to execute either of them?

My overall goal is to be able to make a callback that will be executed for the [following event](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html#send-java.lang.String-K-V-):

```
send(java.lang.String topic, String key, CustomObject info)
```